# Specific date in a case statement in Looker

Tags: case, looker

Writing a case statement in Looker and trying to put a specific date in the else portion. Is there a specific syntax I should be using?  In the else portion I am trying to use a specific instead of the ${Today}, I would like to use 01/01/2050.

```
sql:CASE
when ${Today} < ${XXX} then ${XXX}
ELSE ${Today}
END;;
```

Tried ${TODAY} + 90(just to check syntax) , TRIED '01/01/2050.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing SQL, so the syntax might be a little different for your RDBMS, but you should be okay with a string literal ISO Date value, optionally casted to a date type.

```
sql:CASE
when ${Today} < ${XXX} then ${XXX}
ELSE '2050-01-01'
END;;
```